# Yarn build fails with ENOENT: no such file or directory

Tags: yarnpkg

We automated some of our react applications using Jenkins and Yarn.  However, build is successful for few branches and fails for few

I am finding it to bit difficult to understand.  Example of failed build is provided below

**yarn cache**

Removed yarn cache directories both 'system cache' and 'jenkins cache' (`yarn cache clean` inside jenkins job)

```
[root@jenkins ~]# ls -l /usr/local/share/.cache
ls: cannot access '/usr/local/share/.cache': No such file or directory
```

**Error Message**

```
error https://registry.yarnpkg.com/typescript/-/typescript-4.5.4.tgz: Extracting tar content of undefined failed, the file appears to be corrupt: "ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/var/lib/jenkins/.cache/yarn/v6/npm-typescript-4.5.4-a17d3a0263bf5c8723b9c52f43c5084edf13c2e8-
```

**package.json**

```
"typescript": "^4.1.2"
```

After removing cache folders and rebuilding resulted in following folders being created

**Jenkins cache (/var/lib/jenkins/.cache/yarn/v6)**

```
drwxr-xr-x 3 jenkins jenkins 26 Jan  5 04:44 npm-typescript-4.0.3-153bbd468ef07725c1df9c77e8b453f8d36abba5-integrity
drwxr-xr-x 3 jenkins jenkins 26 Jan  5 04:44 npm-typescript-4.5.4-a17d3a0263bf5c8723b9c52f43c5084edf13c2e8-integrity
```

I would like to understand how and why `npm-typescript-4.0.3` and `npm-typescript-4.5.4` directories were created in `.cache folder` when a different version `"typescript": "^4.1.2"` is mentioned in `package.json`